# Is it possible to find out which page the user was previously browsing?

Tags: html

Is it possible to find out which page the user was previously browsing from current web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you’re using PHP you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but this information can be faked by browsers, so it’s not 100 % foolproof

Comment: Note the referer header is not included when the link is from an HTTPS to an HTTP page. Most browsers enforce this due to security considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Only if the page links to your page.  Then you can look at the referrer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

Or if it's a page on your domain, you can use analytics.

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [Referer HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer).

Answer (score 0):

Try referrer (server side), but other than that - no.

It can't be done client side for security reasons - imagine you page checking visitors browse history - a big no no.